# Haskell Monadic Operations on Lists

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I have the following

```
[3,2,1] >> [1]
= [1,1,1]
```

I don't understand fully why this happens? Looking at >> I would expect [3,2,1] to be the result but I see this is different on lists.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Think about what would happen is the `IO` monad did behave in the analogue way... `putStr "Hello," >> putStr " world"` would be an action that prints _only_ `" world"`.

Comment: It might help if you explained why you expect the results that you suggested.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Think of the type of `(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b`.  In terms of `IO`, that would be "combine two actions of type `IO a` and `IO b` respectively, and produce an action of type `IO b`". Think of `(getLine >> getLine) :: IO String`: it reads two lines from standard input, discards the result of reading the first line, and returns the result of reading the second line.  Similar thing for `([3,2,1] >> ["Hello", "World"]) :: [String]`: choose a number, then choose a string, and return the string, which implicitly discards the number.

Comment: @sacundim: my point has nothing to do with the discarded "returned" parametric data of the monads (that's why I chose an output action, because those have only `()` anyway), it's about the _structure_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I think I just got your point right before I got to your response.  I just submitted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490852/why-isnt-the-list-monad-method-for-defined-as-flip-const) which you might find of interest.

Answer (score 14):

For any monad, you can translate `a >> b` as `a >>= \_ -> b`. In the list monad, the bind operator `(>>=)` is `concatMap` with its arguments flipped, so your example is equivalent to

```
concatMap (\_ -> [1]) [3, 2, 1]
```

which you can evaluate like this.

```
concatMap (\_ -> [1]) [3, 2, 1]
= concat (map (\_ -> [1]) [3, 2, 1])   -- definition of concatMap
= concat [[1], [1], [1]]               -- apply map
= [1, 1, 1]                            -- apply concat
```

Answer (score 7):

`>>` can be defined like this:

```
ma >> mb = ma >>= const mb
```

(That's not its actual definition in the `Monad` instance for `[]`, but that doesn't matter.)

In the list case, for each element in `[1,2,3]`, you get `[1]`, and the overall result is equivalent to `concat [[1],[1],[1]]`, i.e., `[1,1,1]`.

Here's the instance for `[]` in GHC.Base:

```
m >>= k             = foldr ((++) . k) [] m
m >> k              = foldr ((++) . (\ _ -> k)) [] m
```

We concatenate, here using a fold, one copy of the right-hand side for each element in the left-hand side, ignoring whatever that element might be.

Comment: I don't understand the "const mb" thing. const a -> b -> a so I would expect mb to be output. i.e. [1]

Comment: Yes, that's right, `mb` is output. It's output three times because the right-hand side of `>>` and `>>=` is called once for each element of the list on the left-hand side in the case of lists. So you get `[[1],[1],[1]]`.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that `return` for lists is `\x -> [x]`. Perhaps it would be clearer if I rewrote your example in terms of `return`

```
[1,2,3] >> return 1
```

Let's add some do notation sugar

```
do [1,2,3]
   return 1
```

Can you see now? `>>` does not pull the value(s) from its left argument, only the *context* surrounding them. In this case, the context is a 3-element list, or you might say, 3 different choices that are all chosen nondeterministically. Then in each case, `return 1`.

If you instead had done

```
do x <- [1,2,3]
   return x
```

Then you are *not* choosing 1 in each case, but `x`, which represents a particular choice for each "branch". Try to guess what the result of this will be, and then check ghci to see if you were right. Then desugar it, and use equational reasoning to get the correct answer.